# Character of a Representation

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Suppose that we have a representation $V$ of a group $G= SU(2)$ .

Is it true that if $ \chi_V \cdot c  \neq 0$ for some non-zero constant c,  then the trivial representation must be one of the representations in the decomposition of $V$ into irreducible representations.

Is it safe to say that the only representation with constant character is the trivial one?

Comment: I might be confused, but isn't $\chi_T(g)$ a (complex) number?

Comment: I am sorry... I fixed it !

Comment: I don't understand the second paragraph. What's the significance of multiplying by the constant $c$? Isn't that condition equivalent to $\chi_T \neq 0$? In that case, a character has representation zero if and only if its dimension is zero, but it's not true that all representations of nonzero dimension contain the trivial representation. It is true that the only representations with constant character are multiples of the trivial representation.

Comment: Also, it's extremely confusing to call a representation $T$. In Lie theory a capital $T$ usually denotes a torus, or even more specifically a maximal torus (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_torus). It would be less confusing to use a letter like $V$ (for vector space).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan $c$ would be the character of the trivial representation in the case.. and taking the inner product would give me the multiplicity of said representation.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Suppose that I have a representation whose character is $ \chi_V (g)= c+ f(g)$ does it automatically imply  that $ c $ is the character of the trivial representation?

Comment: @Carla: oh, I see. It's also confusing to use $\cdot$ for the inner product of characters, since it looks like multiplication (which is also an operation you can perform on characters!). You should use $\langle \chi, \chi' \rangle$ for the inner product.

Comment: @Carla: I thought I understood your question but now I'm confused again. What is the significance of the function $f(g)$ in the condition $\chi_V(g) = c + f(g)$?

Comment: Suppose I have some representation $V$ with character $\chi_V(g)=   c+f(g)$ where $c$ is some constant. I know that $\chi_V (g)=\sum m_i \chi_{V_i}(g)$ where $V= \oplus m_i V_i$ ( decomposing into irreducibles) Does this mean that $c$ corresponds to the character of the trivial rep?